# "Too many re-renders" Error in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have developed a simple react quiz but I get following error after displaying score : "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {QuestionsResponce} from "./constants/utils";

const Quizz = () => {
    const[currentquestion, setCurrentquestion]=useState(0);
    const[score,setScore]=useState(0);

    const handleCurrentquestion=(iscorrect)=>{
        if(iscorrect===true){
            setScore(score+1);
        }
        const nextquestion=currentquestion+1;
        if(nextquestion < QuestionsResponce.length){
            return setCurrentquestion(nextquestion)
        }

    }
  return (
    <div className="quiz-container">
        <h1>Question{currentquestion+1}/{QuestionsResponce.length}</h1>
        <h1>{QuestionsResponce[currentquestion].Question}</h1>
       <div className="option-section">
      {QuestionsResponce[currentquestion].Options.map((item,index)=>
      
       <button onClick={handleCurrentquestion(item.iscorrect)} key={index}>{item.option}</button>
      )}
    </div>
     {score}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Quizz
```

I've tried to use the `useEffect()` hook to handle the error but no luck.

Comment: In most cases, when receiving such error, you should check your syntax and event handlers.
In your case, the problem is how you have used `onClick` event on your button.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is withing this code block:

```
<button onClick={handleCurrentquestion(item.iscorrect)} key={index}>{item.option}</button>
```

You have to pass a callback to `onClick` and not a function call, otherwise that function will be called immediately and triggers a render which will call the function again and again, resulting in an infinite loop.

Replace the line above by:

```
<button onClick={() => handleCurrentquestion(item.iscorrect)} key={index}>{item.option}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `onClick={handleCurrentquestion(item.iscorrect)}`.
Most probably, this will solve your problem if your error is not originated in `QuestionsResponce`:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {QuestionsResponce} from "./constants/utils";

const Quizz = () => {
    const[currentquestion, setCurrentquestion]=useState(0);
    const[score,setScore]=useState(0);

    const handleCurrentquestion=(iscorrect)=>{
        if(iscorrect===true){
            setScore(score+1);
        }
        const nextquestion=currentquestion+1;
        if(nextquestion < QuestionsResponce.length){
            return setCurrentquestion(nextquestion)
        }

    }
  return (
    <div className="quiz-container">
        <h1>Question{currentquestion+1}/{QuestionsResponce.length}</h1>
        <h1>{QuestionsResponce[currentquestion].Question}</h1>
       <div className="option-section">
      {QuestionsResponce[currentquestion].Options.map((item,index)=>      
       <button onClick={()=>{handleCurrentquestion(item.iscorrect)}} key={index}>{item.option}</button>
      )}
    </div>
     {score}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Quizz
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "Too many re-renders," is likely due to how you're calling the `handleCurrentquestion` function within the `onClick` event handler. When you do `onClick={handleCurrentquestion(item.iscorrect)}`, it calls the function immediately instead of waiting for the button click.

You can fix this by using an arrow function to call `handleCurrentquestion` with the parameter, like this:

```
<button onClick={() => handleCurrentquestion(item.iscorrect)} key={index}>{item.option}</button>
```

By wrapping the `handleCurrentquestion` call in an arrow function, you ensure it's only called when the button is clicked, preventing the excessive re-renders.

Here's the modified code snippet:

```
{QuestionsResponce[currentquestion].Options.map((item, index) => (
  <button onClick={() => handleCurrentquestion(item.iscorrect)} key={index}>
    {item.option}
  </button>
))}
```

This should resolve the "Too many re-renders" error in your React quiz component.